# using caffe training model but get a error

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, caffe, pycaffe

```
I0329 20:38:56.742496 13649 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer data
```

[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc".)
*** Aborted at 1522327138 (unix time) try "date -d @1522327138" if you are using GNU date** 
PC: @     0x7f7ecf688428 gsignal
 **SIGABRT (@0x3e900003551) received by PID 13649 (TID 0x7f7ed1f81b00) from PID 13649; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f7ecf6884b0 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ecf688428 gsignal
    @     0x7f7ecf68a02a abort
    @     0x7f7ed049c84d __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()
    @     0x7f7ed049a6b6 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ed049a701 std::terminate()
    @     0x7f7ed049a919 __cxa_throw
    @     0x7f7ed09e0647 google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::Finish()
    @     0x7f7ed09e087d google::protobuf::internal::VerifyVersion()
    @     0x7f7df22b1967 protobuf_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto::InitDefaultsFileDescriptorSetImpl()
    @     0x7f7ed09e0f75 google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInitImpl()
    @     0x7f7df22aba45 protobuf_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto::InitDefaultsFileDescriptorSet()
    @     0x7f7df22ac5d9 protobuf_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto::AddDescriptorsImpl()
    @     0x7f7ed09e0f75 google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInitImpl()
    @     0x7f7df22acbf5 protobuf_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto::AddDescriptors()
    @     0x7f7ed1dfd6ba (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ed1dfd7cb (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ed1e028e2 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ed1dfd564 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ed1e01da9 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ec6aa9f09 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ed1dfd564 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ec6aaa571 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ec6aa9fa1 dlopen
    @     0x7f7ecfd108dd _PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc
    @     0x7f7ecfd7f54e _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule
    @     0x7f7ecfd80390 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ecfd80658 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ecfd8176b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel
    @     0x7f7ecfceb8b8 (unknown)
    @     0x7f7ecfd44273 PyObject_Call
    @     0x7f7ecfe1a487 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieQx3.png)

Comment: err - might want to clean that up and also give us an indication of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're using the wrong version of libprotobuf:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program
requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but
the installed version is 2.6.1. Please update your library. If you
compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the
same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library. (Version 
verification failed in "google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc".)
```

(edited to make it not one long line)

Comment: the problem have solved, i using pip uninstall protobuf and pip install protobuf==2.6.1 .sometime you need to add sudo